Evaluate: $\int{\cos{\left(2\cot^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}\right)}dx}$
Evaluate: $$\int{\cos{\left(2\cot^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}\right)}dx}.$$

Method 1 Put $x=\cos(2\theta)$; then $\mathrm dx=-2\sin(2\theta)\,\mathrm d\theta$
$$\begin{align*}
I&= \int\cos(2\cot^{-1}\tan\theta)(-2\sin(2\theta))\,\mathrm d\theta\\
&= \int {\cos{\left(2{\left(\frac{π}2-\tan^{-1}(\tan\theta)\right)}\right)}(-2\sin(2\theta))\,\mathrm d\theta}\\ 
&= \int {-2\sin(2\theta)\cos(π-2\theta)\,\mathrm d\theta} =\int{\sin(4\theta)\,\mathrm d\theta}\\
&=-\frac{1}{4}(2\cos^2(2\theta)-1)+c_1\\
&=- \frac{1}{2} x^2 + c\end{align*}$$

Method 2
$$\begin{align*}
I &= \int{\cos{\left(2{\left(\frac{π}{2}-\tan^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}\right)}\right)}\,\mathrm dx}\\
& = \int {-\cos{\left(2\tan^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{x+1}}\right)}\,\mathrm dx}\\
&= \int {-\cos{\left(\tan^{-1}{\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}}\right)}\,\mathrm dx}\\
&= \int -{\cos(\cos^{-1}(x))\,\mathrm dx}\\
&=- \frac{1}{2} x^2 + c\end{align*}$$

Method 3  As
$$\cot^{-1}x=
\begin{cases}\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{x},  & x>0\\π+\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{x}, &x<0
\end{cases} $$
taking case $1$ or $2$ :
$$\begin{align*}I&= \int{\cos{\left(2\tan^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}\right)}\,\mathrm dx}\\
& = \int{\cos{\left(-\tan^{-1}{\frac{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}{x}}\right)}\,\mathrm dx}\\
&= \int {\cos(\cos^{-1}(x))\,\mathrm dx}\\ 
&= \frac{1}{2} x^2 + c\end{align*}$$


Why does the answer of Method 3 not have negative sign? (I know that the answer of Method 1 and 2 is correct.)

Because in method $3$, you result was $-I$?

Method $4$ :  $\cos \left(2 \cot ^{-1}(t)\right)=\frac{t^2-1}{t^2+1}$ could be faster

@Morten could you please tell why is it $-I$ .

Does this answer your question? Integral involving composition of Trig. and Inverse Trig. functions.

You made two mistakes in Method 3:

In case 1 ($x>0$), $2\tan^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}\in(0,\pi)$ is not equal to $-\tan^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}x\in(-\frac\pi2,0)$, but to $-\tan^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}x+\pi$.
In case 2 ($x<0$), $-\tan^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}x\in(0,\frac\pi2)$ is not equal to $\cos^{-1}(x)\in(\frac\pi2,\pi)$, but to $\cos^{-1}(-x)$.

